# In angular how to write strings based on condition of numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular, angularjs-scope

I have `{{ index+1 }}`

I need to display "one" if number is 1 in the expression above.

Display "two" if number is 2 in the expression above and so on up to 6
Display "six" if number is 6.

Since I need only these 1 to 6, I do not prefer to go to JavaScript based number to word format conversion and using it as filter in the above expression. Because, the grunt reports heaps of problem in that solution, so I am looking for a simple conditional display only for this boundary between 1-6.

Comment: `['','one','two','three','four','five','six'][index]`

Comment: @YOU: Sorry, its working fine, in the first one, it displayed empty, obvious as we have empty string, I want from one :) I removed empty string i.e the first one, it works perfectly fine, and you're a sweet :) :) God bless you, happy day you have :) Thank you so much again :)

Comment: @Learner Added an answer, please check.

Comment: @KhalidHussain: That was the answer I was struggling with grunt for long, it has millions of errors in grunt although works fine. So can't use that. The other answer here is very close, just has one error in grunt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using a filter, but you can use a function as well.

An example of a function would be:

```
{{vm.convertToWord(1)}}
```

which would call this and give 'one'

```
    var smallNumbers = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
    vm.convertToWord = function(input) {
      input = parseInt(input, 10);
      if (input < smallNumbers.length) {
        return smallNumbers[input];
      } else {
        return "not valid";
      }
    };
```

See this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ScottL/pen/jrMZZv) for an example using a filter and and a function.

Comment: Thank you, let me try and let you know the outcome

Comment: Scott, it throws error in the return statement in the else part in grunt. It says Expected |'{|' and instead saw |'return|'. But the output is all good, it works fine, but I can't use this code until I clean grunt errors or suggestions like use strict etc. I did use single quote and using strict. How to rectify these 3 errors?

Comment: Thank you, rectified the error, and it was pretty much useful to me, thank you so much for your help and guidance, appreciate it greatly

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when I have small edge cases, I'll just wrap the content in a `<span>` tag and use the `ng-if` directive to make it show on the correct conditions.

To condense the six edge cases into one line, you just use an array evaluation since `{{["one", "two"][0]}}` would evaluate to `one`

Combining these ideas we get something like:

```
<span ng-if="0 <= index && index <= 5"> {{["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"][index]}}</span>
<span ng-if="index < 0 || index > 5">{{index + 1}}</span>
```